# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easy_pdfwebpack_loader'

Tags: javascript, node.js, django

I am trying to make django-easy-pdf work
I followed the instructions here:
https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0-dev1/

This error appears when I run server when I put easy_pdf in INSTALLED_APPS

If I am asking questions in the wrong place, please point me somewhere?

Things I did:

- made sure django-easy-pdf is installed in environment
- rerun npm

Comment: did you `pip install django-easy-pdf` into your virtual environment?

Comment: @Hybrid Yes, I did that already, thank you.

Comment: remove `easy_pdfwebpack_loader` from `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @dan-klasson Ok, I'm so stupid, there's no comma between "easy_pdf" and "webpack_loader", but I wonder why it's not a syntax error instead

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 use `pip3 install django-easy-pdf` and for lower versions `pip install django-easy-pdf`